# How to vertical center a `UISlider` thumb image?

Tags: ios, uislider

I'm customizing an `UISlider` and started drawing my own line which I want then to customize more.

A thing I noticed immediately is that the line seemed not to be draw in the middle of the `UISlider` rectangle. Can someone confirm that this is an intended behavior of `UISlider` or I'm doing something wrong here?

And the outcome is this:

[image]

On the top there are 2 pixel (marked red) and on the bottom there are 4 pixel (also marked red). Why is the line and the thumb image not in the middle?

The code I use is this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  [super drawRect:rect];

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, TRUE, 0);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  // Line selected side
  [self drawLine:context onRect:rect withColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
  UIImage *selectedSide = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

  // Line unselected side
  [self drawLine:context onRect:rect withColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:122/255.0 blue:201/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
  UIImage *unselectedSide = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  [self setMinimumTrackImage:selectedSide forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self setMaximumTrackImage:unselectedSide forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}


- (void) drawLine:(CGContextRef)context onRect:(CGRect)rect withColor:(CGColorRef)color
{
  int halfRectHeight = rect.size.height / 2;

  CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, halfRectHeight, halfRectHeight);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width - halfRectHeight, halfRectHeight);
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: I would guess from the research you have done and the results you found that your answer is “yes”. ‍♂️ I’m not sure anyone would be able to answer the question “why?” Unless the person who wrote the UISwitch UI stumbled across your question and decided to answer it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm wondering why no one else ever noticed that difference and I'm sure Apple would have an explanation for it but it's driving me nuts that I've to figure it out myself, unless I do really something wrong in my code but I haven't touched the thumb image of the Slider and it's not in the vertical middle. Really strange for me.